# Update the current viewed message in a simple text carousel in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a little text carousel I used for my alert messages to my users:

https://jsfiddle.net/wp2cud0d/1/

But I would like to update the current message viewed. Actually it's fixed. So I have all the time `1 of 5` for message 1, `1 of 5` for message 2, `1 of 5` for message 3, ...

How can I fix this please ?

```
$(function() {
  var quotes = $(".message");
  var quoteIndex = -1;
  $('#sliderCount').text(quotes.length);

  function showQuote(change) {
    quoteIndex += change;
    if (quoteIndex < 0) {
      quoteIndex += quotes.length;
    } else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
      quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
    }
    quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
      .fadeIn(1)
      .delay(1000);
  }
  showQuote(1);

  $('#prev').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(-1);
  });

  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(1);
  });
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you asking?? I am not getting anything from your question.

Comment: Add a wrapper to the part you want to replace (the ? in the fiddle) and then from within showQuote, just write the quoteIndex to the wrapper's html, e.g. let's say we call the element "#currentSlide", just do $("#currentSlide").html(quoteIndex) as the last line of showQuote.

Comment: I have a counter like this one `1 of 5` for my messages but I can't find a way to update the `1` with the current message viewed. If I'm reading the second one, I should update to `2 of 5`, ...

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer with a working example - let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wp2cud0d/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a wrapper to the part you want to replace (the ? in the fiddle) and then from within showQuote, just write the quoteIndex to the wrapper's html, e.g. let's say we call the element "#currentSlide", just do $("#currentSlide").html(quoteIndex) as the last line of showQuote. Don't forget to +1 the quoteIndex so that it's no longer zero-indexed in your output:

HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-10">
        <div class="message">
          Message 1
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          Message 2
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          Message 3
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          Message 4
        </div>
        <div class="message">
          Message 5
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-2">
        <span id="currentNumber"></span> of <span id="sliderCount"></span>
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="prev"><</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" id="next">></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
    var quotes = $(".message");
    var quoteIndex = -1;
    $('#sliderCount').text(quotes.length);

function showQuote(change) {
    quoteIndex += change;
    if(quoteIndex < 0) {
        quoteIndex += quotes.length;
    } else if (quoteIndex >= quotes.length) {
        quoteIndex -= quotes.length;
    }
    quotes.stop(true, true).hide().eq(quoteIndex)
        .fadeIn(1)
        .delay(1000);
    $('#currentNumber').html(quoteIndex+1);
    }
showQuote(1);

$('#prev').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(-1);
});

$('#next').on('click', function() {
    showQuote(1);
});

});
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dpemdtte/)